# methods of JQUERY inclusion to enable jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery code in my HTML page with help of CDN but I can't test it without internet connection. I am just developing.

How to enable Jquery code locally apart from Google's CDN

Answer (score 4):

Download `js` file save it in local and then you can use native fallback to local version if your `cdn` fails to load.

**Ex**

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="localpathhere/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<!--The second line of code checks whether jquery has been loaded correctly else it will 
write a new script where local file gets referred-->
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing in local environments, download the JS file and place in your local computer and reference to it.

Sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_YOUR_JS_FILE.JS"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need an internet connection to download the jQuery file once.  http://jquery.com/download/

Then just include the a path to the local jquery.js file in your html.
E.g. if you have your file in a folder Content, it will look like this.

```
   <script src="/Content/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just perform following steps:

- Download js file from the CDN itself with the same name.
- Place that file in your folder.
- Write `<script>` tag following way.

  ```
  <script type ="text/javascript"  src="Jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  ```